# PHP spl_autoload_register can't load class with require scope when namespace use

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

Ok!!! Now, i feel like clue less why spl_autoload_register() can't able to load the class.

My folder structure is like this..

- application

  - controller

    - welcome.php
- system

  - core

    - BaseController.php
    - Load.php
- index.php

My BaseController.php code

```
<?php
namespace system\core;

class BaseController {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
    }

    private function loader($className) {              
        $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
        $fileName  = '';
        $namespace = '';
        if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
            $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
            $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
            $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
        $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

        require $fileName;
    }
}
```

My Load.php code

```
<?php
namespace system\core;

class Load  {
    public function view()
    {
        echo "Method for loading view";
    }
}
```

My welcome.php code

```
<?php
class Welcome extends system\core\BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $obj_load = new Load();
        $obj_load->view();
    }
}
```

My index.php code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once "system/core/BaseController.php";
require_once "application/controller/welcome.php";
$welcome = new welcome();
echo $welcome->index();
```

When i'm executing this code(index.php) I'm getting following error...

```
Fatal error: Class 'Load' not found in /var/www/nut/test/application/controller/welcome.php on line 5
```

But, If i remove the namespace from Load.php i'm not getting any error. I can't able to understand why that namespace(used in Load.php) is creating error.

Any thought...

Regards

Comment: Your class name is `system\core\Load`; you're trying to load `'system/core/'.$className . '.php';` which evaluates to a file called `system/core/system\core\Load.php`....

Comment: Your autoloader should be converting the namespace separators in the classname to folder separators, and using those rather than trying to hardcode them

Comment: @MarkBaker I removed my autoloader code & now using PHP-FIG example code as shown in this link -> http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

But, still i'm getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark has noted, you are using the wrong character when trying to include your files. [This](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards) page should make things clearer.

Edit:
You had quite a few mistakes in your code. The whole point of namespaces is that you have to reference them properly (as well as declare them properly, you failed to do both, that's why the autoload code didn't work) Also the autoload code had no real chance to run since you had it hidden inside a constructor to a class that never gets loaded in the first place. Try this:

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once("system/core/AutoLoader.php");
$welcome = new \application\controller\welcome();
echo $welcome->index();
```

welcome.php (note the lower case class name and the addition of the namespace)

```
<?php

namespace application\controller;

class welcome extends \system\core\BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $obj_load = new \system\core\Load();
        return $obj_load->view();
    }
}
```

Load.php

```
<?php
namespace system\core;

class Load  {
    public function view()
    {
        return "Method for loading view";
    }
}
```

BaseController.php

```
<?php
namespace system\core;

class BaseController {
//  public function __construct() {
//      spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
//  }
//
//  private function loader($className) {
//      $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
//      $fileName  = '';
//      $namespace = '';
//      if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
//          $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
//          $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
//          $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
//      }
//      $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
//
//      require $fileName;
//  }
}
```

new file: system\core\AutoLoader.php

```
<?php

namespace system\core;

class AutoLoader {

    static public function loader($className) {
        $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
        $fileName  = '';
        $namespace = '';
        if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
            $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
            $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
            $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
        $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

        require $fileName;
    }

}

spl_autoload_register(array('\system\core\AutoLoader', 'loader'));
```

I also changed the code to return the string instead of displaying it since you are already echoing it inside index.php

Comment: I removed my autoloader code & now using PHP-FIG example code as shown in this link -> http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

But, still i'm getting same error.

Comment: I got it. Learned some lesson. Thanks for your prompt response.